# Can a Safari extension save cookies?

Tags: ajax, cookies, safari-extension

Is it possible for Safari extensions to save cookies locally instead of using the browser's cookies? The problem with HTTPS ajax requests bringing up a login popup is starting to rankle me. I know how to login to Google services from a command line script using curl and perl/php. If I can save my cookies somewhere on the local filesystem I can avoid all this hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Safari extensions have no access whatsoever to the local filesystem. You can only use cookies directly from the browser or local storage.